# SQL Server - Transform multiple columns into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a wide table that contains 60+ columns for UPS/Fedex tracking numbers. I am trying to reduce the number of columns and have a parent to child relationship.

```
SELECT 
    [TRACKING-NO1], [TRACKING-NO2], [TRACKING-NO3], [TRACKING-NO4],
    [TRACKING-NO5], [TRACKING-NO6], [TRACKING-NO7], [TRACKING-NO8],
    [TRACKING-NO9], [TRACKING-NO10]
FROM 
    [CustomerServiceOrderEntry].[dbo].[InvoicedOrdersTempTable]
WHERE
    [TRACKING-NO2] IS NOT NULL
```

The output returns a list of all the tracking numbers in one row (60+) columns. If there are child tracking numbers, then columns 2 - 60 will be populated; If there are no child tracking numbers, 2 - 60 will be NULL.

What I would like to do is have a parent tracking number and the associated child tracking number, and a flag to indicate it is a child.

[Current Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddd5g.png)

[New Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWKFY.png)

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `UNPIVOT`for convert columns to row.

But `UNPIVOT` does not returns any rows that not have child columns.

That' why, we need to determine  this kind of rows additionally.

```
SELECT 
    [TRACKING-NO1] TrackingNumberParent ,
    'TRUE' TrackingNumberChildren
    ,TrackingNumberChild 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM [CustomerServiceOrderEntry].[dbo].[InvoicedOrdersTempTable] ) SRC 
        UNPIVOT( TrackingNumberChild FOR COL IN (
            [TRACKING-NO2],
            [TRACKING-NO3],
            [TRACKING-NO4],
            [TRACKING-NO5],
            [TRACKING-NO6],
            [TRACKING-NO7],
            [TRACKING-NO8],
            [TRACKING-NO9],
            [TRACKING-NO10])) PVT
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    [TRACKING-NO1] TrackingNumberParent, 
    'FALSE' TrackingNumberChildren, 
    NULL TrackingNumberChild 
FROM 
    [CustomerServiceOrderEntry].[dbo].[InvoicedOrdersTempTable] 
WHERE 
    [TRACKING-NO2] IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    TrackingNumberParent
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed! Good job!

Answer (score 0):

The following should be considerably faster as it only takes a single pass over the base table...

```
SELECT 
    TrackingNumberParent = iot.[TRACKING-NO1],
    TrackingNumberChildren = CASE WHEN ctn.[TRACKING-NO] IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END,
    TrackingNumberChild = ctn.[TRACKING-NO]
FROM
    [CustomerServiceOrderEntry].[dbo].[InvoicedOrdersTempTable] iot
    OUTER APPLY ( 
                SELECT 
                    tn.COL_NO,
                    tn.[TRACKING-NO]
                FROM ( VALUES 
                    (2, iot.[TRACKING-NO2]), (3, iot.[TRACKING-NO3]), (4, iot.[TRACKING-NO4]),
                    (5, iot.[TRACKING-NO5]), (6, iot.[TRACKING-NO6]), (7, iot.[TRACKING-NO7]), 
                    (8, iot.[TRACKING-NO8]), (9, iot.[TRACKING-NO9]), (10, iot.[TRACKING-NO10])
                    ) tn (COL_NO, [TRACKING-NO])
                WHERE   
                    (
                        tn.[TRACKING-NO] IS NOT NULL 
                        OR 
                        tn.COL_NO = 2   
                    )
                ) ctn;
```